# How to deal with too much descriptive question?

Tags: discussion, questions

How to deal with such a question [AVD Manager on Android Studio 1.5.1 and install to a custom location emulator won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272258/avd-manager-on-android-studio-1-5-1-and-install-to-a-custom-location-emulator-wo)

Comment: Well, you could add a comment. If you think it's "not useful", you can downvote it.  (I personally wouldn't do that in this case, though.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the general case where a question has a lot of off-topic rambling, edit the question to remove the extraneous content.

In the case where a question has way too much code, vote to close it as not having a **short** self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

In **this** case, the question is *fine*. Be less lazy and read it. There is really very little text in this question, and it's *all* relevant to the problem.

Comment: I think you're right. Images are occupied more space.

Comment: Note that re-structuring the content so that the most important information is at the start can also help a lot here, especially with a long question that actually needs all of the information it has.  Including the important parts at the start so that people can determine if the question is worth their time, and then the details for those who feel it's something that interests them, helps a lot.